# Foursquare API - Search By Address

Tags: ios, search, foursquare

I am using the venues/search API in my app and I am getting some strange results: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search.

If I send in the query "1 Irving", as if a user is searching for an address, the list of results returned by Foursquare contains irrelevant venues.  From looking at the documentation, I would guess that this is because the "query" parameter of the API is only searching against venue names, and not addresses.

If that is the case, does anyone know if there is any way to get the API to search against address information also?  It seems the Foursquare and Swarm apps both do this when searching, as the results for "1 Irving" are much more relevant when I try there.

Edit: including screenshot from Foursquare app

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [venues/search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) documentation it mentions that if you set `intent=match` you can include an `address` parameter.

> Finds venues that are are nearly-exact matches for the given
>   parameters. This intent is highly sensitive to the provided location.
>   We recommend using this intent only when trying to correlate an
>   existing place database with Foursquare's. The results will be sorted
>   best match first, taking distance and spelling mistakes/variations
>   into account.
>
> query and ll are the only required parameters for this intent, but
>   matching also supports phone, **address, city, state, zip**, and twitter.
>   There's no specified format for these parameters—we do our best to
>   normalize them and drop them from the search if unsuccessful.

However you still need to provide a `query` parameter that would be the venue name. I don't believe an endpoint exists to lookup a venue with nothing but an address.

Comment: I think this is as probably as close to what I was looking for as the API provides, thanks.

Comment: we noticed that the Foursquare app does a much better job of finding relevant results when typing in the specific string "1 Irving".  It seems to match on the "Irving" even though that is an address and not a venue name.  Is there any exposed way in the API to get similar results to this? Since "query" is required in your answer I'm not sure that would work the same as how it is displayed in the Foursquare app. -- I posted a screenshot of the Foursquare app and results in my original question.

Comment: The screenshot you've posted is using the `venues/search` API with `intent=checkin` and `query=1 irving`

Answer (score 0):

Just from taking a quick look at the docs, it seems like you can just pass the location in as the `near` object rather than the `query` object.  The docs specifically say "A search term to be applied against venue names."

Comment: Hey, sorry, maybe it wasn't clear from the question, but I'm looking for a way for the user's search term to be applied against address information.  So if the user types "1 Irving" I would like results to display for addresses that match.

Comment: @haplo1384 Yes, exactly. `near` is the parameter that takes address information. `query` is for keyword searches. Read the docs.

Comment: I did read the docs. I want the users to be able to search on "1 Irving" and the results MATCH on that address text, not return anything near that address.